# How To Stop Apache Logging Client Denied By Server Errors

Tags: apache-2.2, firewall, .htaccess, spam

I get an annoying amount of spam traffic from the Ukrane, Russia, Korea etc. I have setup rules in my .htaccess file to block all of these countries and it's working great. The problem i have now is my error logs are insanely large. Last weeks log was 2gb. The entire log is just full of

> client denied by server configuration:...

I dont need to read these. They are making it impossible for me to monitor genuine errors and the disk space they take up is also annoying. Is there a better way to do this or a way to stop apache from writing these messages to the log?

Its important that i still have errors written to this log. If i block everything that is an error or lower i will loose out on everything that i currently use the error log for. I want errors to still get written to the log. It helps me track any errors in the code.

Comment: blocking all errors is going to mean i miss out on genuine errors? i monitor this log daily so i need to make sure that i get to see errors that are important.

Comment: `grep -v "client denied by server configuration"`

Comment: @ceejayoz It may be a duplicate, but the older question doesn't have any good answers.

Comment: @kasperd Feel free to add good ones there, then. :-)